# Solr can't find JDBC driver

Tags: java, ubuntu, lucene, solr

I haven't done anything with Java in years, so I'm trying to get this done as simply as possible. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. So far I've just done:

```
apt-get install solr-jetty libmysql-java
```

and set up all my config files to pull in documents from my MySQL database. Now, however, I'm getting this in the logs when I try to do a full import:

```
SEVERE: Full Import failed
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
```

Now I'm a bit stuck, because if apt installing libmysql-java didn't get me the JDBC driver, I have no idea what will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These error means that your mysql dirver cannot be found on java classpath and you should just add it to it.

In case of Jetty you should put your database driver in `$JETTY_HOME/lib/ext` directory. Just put there symbolic link or copy jar file.

If you don't know where is MySql JDBC jar file you can check it using these command:

```
dpkg-query -L libmysql-java
```

Or you can just simply download these driver from MySql download page.

PS. I have never used Jetty and I found these information here: http://content.liferay.com/4.2/doc/installation/liferay_4_installation_guide/multipage/ch03.html#d0e893, point 9, Jetty 5.1 installation.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thank you so much!

Comment: Works. Why can't I put it in "lib" but have to use "lib/ext"? Do I use "ext" when I include a jar?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up just symlinking to .jars from /usr/share/java; maybe there's a better way though.

```
ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar \
/usr/share/solr/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar
sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql.jar /usr/share/solr/WEB-INF/lib/mysql.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

put the file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` (or its *symbol link*) to this directory:

`/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/`

I know this is for tomcat case but you can do the similar.